# Pipe ffmpeg stream to sox rec

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, sox

I am reading an audio stream via ffpmeg like this:

`ffmpeg -i http://icecast.radiovox.org:8000/live.ogg -f mp3 filename`

and want to pipe it to a sox command:

`rec filename rate 32k silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%.`

Ultimately, what I am trying to achieve, is to record the audio from a live Icecast stream of a talk show.  I only want recordings though of the individual's speaking.  Everytime there is silence, I want to stop the recording and start a new one once they start speaking again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What difficulty did you meet?  I tried myself and the only problem I noticed in using the example given in the sox man page is that `sox -` may have trouble understanding the input format from just a few bytes.

Try going through flac, it worked here:

`ffmpeg -i http://icecast.radiovox.org:8000/live.ogg -f flac - |
 sox - song.ogg silence 1 0.50 0.1% 1 2.0 0.1% : newfile : restart`

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg supports the sox format too for piping to avoid format compatibility problems.

```bash
ffmpeg -i http://icecast.radiovox.org:8000/live.ogg -f sox - |
 sox -t sox - song.ogg silence 1 0.50 0.1% 1 2.0 0.1% : newfile : restart
```